# Get the word under the mouse cursor in Windows

Tags: windows, automation, accessibility, translation, nlp

Greetings everyone,

A friend and I are discussing the possibility of a new project: A translation program that will pop up a translation whenever you hover over any word in any control, even static, non-editable ones.  I know there are many browser plugins to do this sort of thing on webpages; we're thinking about how we would do it system-wide (on Windows).

Of course, the key difficulty is figuring out the word the user is hovering over.  I'm aware of MSAA and Automation, but as far as I can tell, those things only allow you to get the entire contents of a control, not the specific word the mouse is over.

I stumbled upon this (proprietary) application that does pretty much exactly what we want to do:  http://www.gettranslateit.com/

Somehow they are able to get the exact word the user is hovering over in almost any application (It seems to have trouble in a few apps, notably Windows Explorer).  It even grabs text out of obviously custom-drawn controls, somehow.  At first I thought it must be using OCR.  But even when I shrink the font so far down that the text becomes a completely unreadable blob, it can still recognize words perfectly.  (And yet, it doesn't recognize anything if I change the font to Wingdings.  But maybe that's by design?)

Any ideas as to how it's achieving this seemingly impossible task?

EDIT: It doesn't work with Wingdings, but it does work with some other nonsense fonts, so I've confirmed it can't be OCR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could capture the GDI calls that output text to the display, and then figure out which word's bounding box the cursor falls in.

Comment: Ahah!  Sure enough, when I take a look with dumpbin (thanks Jeff), it looks like this is exactly what they're doing.

Comment: @Paul: do you remember exactly which calls were used?

Answer (score 2):

Well, for GDI controls you can get the position and size of the control, and you can usually get the font info.  For example, with [static text controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760767%28VS.85%29.aspx#text_static_control) you'd use [WM_GETFONT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632624%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  Then once you have that you can get the position of the mouse relative to the position of the control and use one of the [font functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144821%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), perhaps something like [GetTextExtentPoint32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144938%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to figure out what is under the cursor.  I'm pretty sure the answer lies in that direction...

You can run `dumpbin /imports` on the other application and see what APIs they are calling.