# what OCR algorithm does Microsoft Office Document Imaging use? Can I use it without installing office 2003?

Tags: python, windows, ms-word, ocr

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811550/ocring-application-text-not-scanned-not-captchas/5811626), I found a program, [JOCR](http://home.megapass.co.kr/~woosjung/Product_JOCR.html) that has good results. It turns out it just uses Microsoft Office Document Imaging to do the OCR for it using COM. That works for me - I can spend some time trying to get it to work from Python (where I need it).

My questions are: what OCR algorithm do they use? Is it possible to get it (or one like it - tesseract and ocropus seem to only work with scanned images or pictures, but MODI OCR works great with on-screen text) elsewhere? Is it possible to install it on a computer without installing all of Office 2003?

Comment: Office is propriatary and so is their OCR most likely. Have you tried looking into tesseract? Also I don't see how this question relates to python?